# Get Default Temporary Folder in Mac using Mono

Tags: c#, macos, mono, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I need my application to write buffer data to the temporary folder.When i used

```
System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()
```

in Mac it returned a string

```
 var/folders/r3/blah..blah/T/
```

(blah.blah = some random letters and digits)

Where exactly is this folder located?

Doesn't Mac have a folder like `Temp` in windows to place the temporary files?

Comment: It turns out that it is the temp folder for mac. Refer http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Sorry for the late response.Was busy with some other work.So this itself is the temp folder.So where is it located exactly?

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer :**

For C#, `Path.GetTempPath()` function returns value stored in environment variable `$TMPDIR`. 
Value of `$TMPDIR` in general is of following form :

```
/var/folders/{2 character random-string}/{random-string}/T
```

**Long answer**

Mac OS stores system-wide temporary files at : `/var/folder/../T`

This path can be found out using environment variable `$TMPDIR`

Please note that `/tmp` or `/var/tmp` are also temporary directory but its data is usually deleted upon rebooting Mac OS.

Also, temporary directory depends upon what application you are using.

So, gist is there is no universal temp directory in mac os.

Check out this links for more details :

[Where is the temp folder?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94981)

[What is "/var/folders"?](http://magnusviri.com/Mac/what-is-var-folders.html)